# PHP Получить значение в массиве

Tags: php, массивы, wordpress, woocommerce, объекты

В PHP файле вывожу переменную (в ней как я понимаю массив)

```html
$WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT = new WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT();
print_r($WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT);
```

Как получить в переменную значение элемента `[6] =&gt; product_ids`
из массива (объекта) ниже

```html
WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT Object
(
    [meta_type:protected] =&gt; post
    [internal_meta_keys:protected] =&gt; Array
        (
            [0] =&gt; discount_type
            [1] =&gt; coupon_amount
            [2] =&gt; expiry_date
            [3] =&gt; date_expires
            [4] =&gt; usage_count
            [5] =&gt; individual_use
            [6] =&gt; product_ids
            [7] =&gt; exclude_product_ids
            [8] =&gt; usage_limit
            [9] =&gt; usage_limit_per_user
            [10] =&gt; limit_usage_to_x_items
            [11] =&gt; free_shipping
            [12] =&gt; product_categories
            [13] =&gt; exclude_product_categories
            [14] =&gt; exclude_sale_items
            [15] =&gt; minimum_amount
            [16] =&gt; maximum_amount
            [17] =&gt; customer_email
            [18] =&gt; _used_by
            [19] =&gt; _edit_lock
            [20] =&gt; _edit_last
        )

    [object_id_field_for_meta:protected] =&gt; 
)
```

Comment: Это не php. Потрудитесь отредактировать свой вопрос так, чтобы он содержал синтаксически правильный код.

Comment: Это вывод переменной в PHP 
//
$WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT = new WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT();
print_r($WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT);
,,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы не можете получить их на прямую, смотрите код в class-wc-data-store-wp.php.
Используйте метод get_internal_meta_keys() и в нем уже выбирайте элемент.

```
$WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT = new WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT();
$product_ids = $WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT->get_internal_meta_keys()[6]
```

Answer (score 0):

Вам нужно обратиться к элементу объекта. И записать его в переменную.

$x = $WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT->6; //где 6 - это имя элемента.

Comment: Выдает HTTP ERROR 500 именно на эту строку 
$x = $WC_Coupon_Data_Store_CPT->6;